# Setting predicate to search in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, predicate

I need to perform search Core Data entities in my app for iPhone.

In my Core Data I have an entity 'myEntity', that has two properties 'stringOne' and 'stringTwo'; both defined as NSString.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stringOne contains[cd] %@", self.keyword4Search]; 
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

My code above only search entities that contains keyword4Search in stringOne only.

What I need is to search entities that contains keyword4Search in [stringOne OR stringTwo].

---

I expect kind of

```
predicateWithFormat:@"stringOne or stringTwo contains[cd] %@", self.keyword4Search];
```

where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stringOne contains[cd] %@ OR stringTwo contains[cd] %@", self.keyword4Search, self.keyword4Search];
```